# How can I immediately know whether I have Pokeballs or not?

Tags: pokemon-go

I often select a wild Pokémon to catch it, only to get the message "No Poké Balls" after waiting a few seconds. It is time wasted.

**QUESTION:** On the main screen, how can I immediately see whether I have Poké Balls?

[image]

Comment: It's not time wasted if you didn't have Pokeballs to start with. In fact it's time saved, since you're not wasting time throwing Pokeballs at a Pokemon.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: Selecting a Pokémon with my fat fingers can take up to 20 seconds, and then the screen load takes a few seconds, then there is the Pokémon's animation, before I can finally the my Poké Balls count. This time would be better spent moving on.

Comment: And what exactly are you moving on to? The game does not pause when you select a Pokemon on your map. It keeps going in the background. I think you're overestimating how much time you're "wasting".

Comment: Move on = Keep walking and getting items from the numerous Pokéstops around, while paying attention to the real environment. That already takes more time than I can devote, as I walk fast and the area is very active.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. You either have to go into your inventory and check, and keep count. Or when catching a Pokemon you can see a small number at the bottom, that's your current count.